# PHP: Preg replace string with nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, wildcard, vbulletin

I'm new to `preg_replace()` and I've been trying to get this to work, I couldn't so StackOverflow is my last chance.

I have a string with a few of these:

```
('pm_IDHERE', 'NameHere');">
```

I want it to be replaced with nothing, so it would require 2 wildcards for `NameHere` and `pm_IDHERE`.

But I've tried it and failed myself, so could someone give me the right code please, and thanks :)

Comment: Can you show what did not work? Its almost always better (for you) if someone can show you where you went wrong, thus .. you understand the expression better. The result of asking for 'the right code' on SO is undefined.

Comment: I'm cofused as to what you need. Can you provide an example of what you're doing and what is not working? Have a look at the PHP manual for some good examples of how preg works: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: $str = preg_replace("#\('pm_(.+?)', '(.*?)');#si", "\1", $str);

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

You are almost there, you just have to make the replacement an empty string and escape the parenthesis properly, otherwise they will be treated as capture group (which you don't need btw):

```
$str = preg_replace("#\('pm_.+?', '.*?'\);#si", "", $str);
```

You probably also don't need the modifiers `s` and `i` but that is up to you.

---

**Old answer:**

Probably [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is sufficient:

```
$str = "Some string that contains pm_IDHERE and NameHere";
$str = str_replace(array('pm_IDHERE', 'NameHere'), '', $str);
```

If this is not what you mean and `pm_IDHERE` is actually something like `pm_1564` then yes, you probably need regular expressions for that. But if `NameHere` has no actual pattern or structure, you cannot replace it with regular expression.
And you definitely have to explain better what kind of string **you have** and what kind of string **you have want to replace**.